# How to make a Firefox extension that will call my custom file downloader?

Tags: firefox

I am trying to make a Firefox extension that will launch my custom downloader.  The downloader is already installed on my users computer.  It will only be called when the user is on my website.  I already have been working on this and have it launching a notifier when the user clicks on my link.  But I do not know how to launch my external program.  Can someone give me some guidance as to how to do this?  Also, my user is on Firefox 45. (they can't upgrade at this time)  Thanks.

Comment: So I found an example, but when I run it I get an error.  Here is the line that gives the error that I tried to run in the console.

var myfile = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
TypeError: Components.classes is undefined

I was running this in the Firefox extension debug console.